# What's the story of the serpent Karkotaka deceiving sage Narada?

Tags: mahabharata, narada

In the Nala-Damayanti story [narrated](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03053.htm) by sage Vrihadaswa to Yudhishthira, there's [mention of](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03066.htm) the Naga, Karkotaka, who bites and disfigures Nala for his own good.

But what's the story of Karkotaka deceiving sage Narada? Why did he deceive Narada?

> King Nala saw a mighty conflagration that was raging in that dense forest. And in the midst of that conflagration, he heard the voice of some creature,
>   repeatedly crying aloud, 'O righteous Nala, come hither.' And answering,
>   'Fear not,' he entered into the midst of the fire and beheld a mighty
>   Naga lying in coils. And the Naga with joined hands, and trembling, spake
>   unto Nala, saying, '**O king, that I am a snake, Karkotaka by name. I had
>   deceived the great Rishi Narada of high ascetic merit**, and by him have I
>   been cursed in wrath, O king of men, even in words such as these: 'Stay
>   thou here like an immobile thing, until one Nala taketh thee hence. And,
>   indeed, on the spot to which he will carry thee, there shalt thou he
>   freed from my curse. It is for that curse of his that I am unable to stir
>   one step. I will instruct thee in respect of thy welfare. It behoveth
>   thee to deliver me. I will be thy friend. There is no snake equal to me.
>   I will be light in thy hands. Taking me up, do thou speedily go hence.'
>   Having said this, that prince of snakes became as small as the thumb. And
>   taking him up, Nala went to a spot free from fire.

Comment: The story I always heard is that Karkotaka cheated Narada in a game of dice, and Narada immediately saw through it and cursed him.  But I'm not sure if it has a scriptural basis.  In any case, it's kind of ironic that the story of Nala and Damayanti ends with Nala learning how to cheat at dice.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes, that's the story I read in a couple of blogs too. Yudhishtira [says](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03079.htm) 'O illustrious one, I desire to learn the science of dice from thee.' - I don't think he wanted to learn how to cheat, that's very unlike Yudhishtira.

Comment: @Keshav The question is why did **Narada** play dice?

Answer (score 2):

Dice is the "Lord Chance" incarnate-- the incomprehensible mix called destiny or Karmic comeback. Karkotaka is our spiritual power, our kundalini, that can manifest as magical powers or siddhis. If we use our siddhis to mess with destiny, influence karma or "cheat at dice" we will be punished by having our spiritual power locked up-- frozen by the curse of Vishnu's mediator Narada.

To unlock our spiritual potential from this abominable crime we must go through the purification of intense humility. Thus the body of King Nala turning old and decrepit. By losing pride in our body, we lose interest in messing with destiny and we can grow spiritually again.

Comment: Welcome! Answers on this site should be backed up with proper sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)

Comment: This is not an answer - but a related piece of info/correlation : https://ariyalur.nic.in/tourism/places-of-interest/ : there is a place in Tamil Nadu called Kamarasavalli where Karkotaka is said to have worshipped Shiva.